# Boolean expression explanation

Tags: boolean-algebra

Could someone explain how to get the following  Boolean expression in its simplest form, I am having difficulties working it out step by step

$$A+B+A*B$$

Comment: If you want to visualise what it means, just think of $A \cup B \cup (A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A + B + AB = A(B + 1) + B = A + B$ (because $B + 1$ is always 1), so it simplifies to a simple OR function. This can be verified by the truth table as well.

Comment: But only iff $AB=0.$

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis why only iff $AB = 0$?

Comment: $A+B+AB=A+B\Leftrightarrow AB=0.$

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis That doesn't seem right. If both $A$ and $B$ are true, then $AB \neq 0$ but $A + B + AB = A + B$ still holds.

Comment: But $AB=0$ indeed, because $B+1=1\Leftrightarrow B=0.$ No ?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis No. $B + 1 = 1$ regardless of the value of $B$.